# Can't chown despite no error messages

Tags: 14.04, chown

I got /dev/sda9 NTFS partition mounted r/w under /data

```
/dev/sda9 on /data type fuseblk (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
```

and I got the folder PhotoCopy to which I need recursively change owner

```
~ > whoami
anton
~ > sudo /bin/chown -R anton:anton /data/PhotoCopy
~ > ls -l /data
...
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 нояб. 12 10:17 PhotoCopy/
...
```